# Is there a way to capture the Package ID using Salesforce CLI (sfdx) command?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, package-install

I am trying to get the ID of a specific package name using the command below:

```bash
PACKAGE_ID_CORE=$(sfdx force:package:list --targetdevhubusername HubOrg --json | 
grep -A1 '"Name": "MyTestPackage"' | grep '"Id"' | awk -F':' '{print $2}' | tr -d '",')
echo "PACKAGE_ID_CORE: $PACKAGE_ID_CORE"
```

It shows blank instead of the actual Package ID. Output: `PACKAGE_ID_CORE:`

The `MyTestPackage` definitely exists when I did the command: `sfdx force:package:list --targetdevhubusername HubOrg --json`.  It displayed the output below (Note: I have multiple packages as per below):

```json
sfdx force:package:list output: {
  "status": 0,
  "result": [
    {
      "Id": "0Hxxx",
      "SubscriberPackageId": "0333xxx",
      "Name": "MyTestPackage",
      "Description": null,
      "NamespacePrefix": null,
      "ContainerOptions": "Unlocked",
      "ConvertedFromPackageId": null,
      "Alias": "",
      "IsOrgDependent": "No",
      "PackageErrorUsername": null,
      "CreatedBy": "0053xxx"
    },
    {
      "Id": "0Hxxx",
      "SubscriberPackageId": "0333xxx",
      "Name": "Core",
      "Description": null,
      "NamespacePrefix": "test",
      "ContainerOptions": "Managed",
      "ConvertedFromPackageId": null,
      "Alias": "Core",
      "IsOrgDependent": "N/A",
      "PackageErrorUsername": null,
      "CreatedBy": "0053xxx"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `jq`! It's much easier than trying to string together `grep` and `awk` to get data out of a JSON payload. With your example JSON in `test.json`, you can do

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.result | map(select(.Name == "MyTestPackage")) | .[0].Id'
```

and get back

```
0Hxxx
```

Comment: Thanks David. ChatGPT was recommending `jq` too :D I'm trying my best to stay away from non-default plugins as installing these is a bit challenging with our protected CI servers but I guess, this might be the way forward so I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone would just like to use `grep` then this command would display the package ID:

```bash
PACKAGE_ID_CORE=$(sfdx force:package:list | grep -E 'MyTestPackage' | grep -o '0Ho\w*')
echo "PACKAGE_ID_CORE: $PACKAGE_ID_CORE"
```

Else, David's answer above using `jq` works well too.